# How do you reposition an expandable banner in html?

Tags: html

I'm using google web designer and I need to make an expanded panel expand from the centre out. At the moment the choices I have are only top, bottom, left right.

I also need to make the background of the expanded panel transparent. (it's currently white by default.)

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not expand your banner center out.

The only option you have is Top, Bottom, Left & Right. So don't waste your time on that.

For transparent background, you can style your main div as background-color:transparent,

But, the publisher may put your html5 div on another div with some background color (Yes, usually the publisher want to distinguish the banner from the website content)

But that part is negotiable, if the publisher approved transparency, you can test your banner on DoubleClick Studio by going:
creative-> Preview tab -> select 'Show Details' button -> On the left hand side choose 'Display Option' -> at the buttom of the opened dialog, you will see a checkbox named: 'Transparen', check that.

But remember it is a test when the Media Agency publishes you banner to the Publisher UI they can remove the transparency, so first get approval for that.